# Set Default music player to Banshee, yet it's still Rythmbox?

Tags: software-center, uninstall, banshee, rhythmbox, default-programs

I kind of have two questions, that tie into each other.

1. I want to set Banshee as the default music player. It seems simple enough. Go to "systems settings > Details > Default Applications" and change "Music"from "Rhythmbox" to "Banshee". But, this did not work. How do I make this work?
2. How do I uninstall Rhythmbox? I tried uninstalling it from the Ubuntu Software Center, yet Rhythbox updates still showed up in my "System Updates." I don't want that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To completly remove an application you can run:

```
sudo apt-get purge packagename
```

Comment: How to I get rid of the updates for Rhythmbox? [http://prntscr.com/cv0xg](http://prntscr.com/cv0xg)